# Is this possible to make as a option dialog in Java?

Tags: java, dialog

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/2637/dialogo.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/2637/dialogo.png)

I'm wondering how I could make this into a popup dialog.  I designed this with Netbeans gui editor.  I looked at option dialog, but all the examples only had a textfield or a combobox, not more than one thing like I have.  So what would be the best way to make this in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend [`JDialog`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)

See [the dialogs tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a JDialog form

Answer (score 0):

You could extend JDialog, then use GridBagLayout to implement GUI like that (actually JFrame also works, you just need to specify some setting like default close operations and stuff), if you use JDialog, set setModel() to true to block other GUI just like a pop up window.